# VR Play postion Sync over the network

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, htc-vive

**I am developing a multiplayer game where a normal character controller user and VR user can participate. So there are two modes of the games through a user can join:**

1. **Normal**
2. **VR Mode**

I am able to manage these modes and user can participate with any mode but the problem is Normal Player(charcter controller) is unable
 to view VR controller(HTC vive Controllers) as these objects are becomes off on the side of character controller. So how do I view VR controller at normal player that what VR player is doing.

*I make an object and tried to imitiate it position and rotation with respect to VR controller but it is not working as Imitating source(VR controllers) are off (at the normal player side but working in VR mode) and their postion is not changing. How do you manage to make multiplayer game with VR + normal player? or what else the solution.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem using these  steps after trying hard three four days. These step are given below so that future user don't get stuck in this problem as there are no other comprehensive guide available:

1. Make one **Gameobject for Head** (simple cube) with [Network Identity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkIdentity.html) and [network transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkTransform.html)
2. Make one **Gameobject for(right) Controller** (simple cube) with Network Identity and network transform
3. Make one **Gameobject for(left) other Controller** (simple cube) with network Identity and network transform
4. Make prefab of all above gameobjects.
5. Add all three prefabs into [Network Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.html) (registered Spawnable prefabs list)
6. delete three prefab from scene
7. Added below script(See comments for details) into my vr player and assign respective prefabs and gameobjects

   ```
   public class VRPlayerCtrl : NetworkTransform {

   //source gameobjects head, left and right controller object of htc vive prefab

   public GameObject rightContSource;

   public GameObject leftContSource;

   public GameObject headObjSource;


   //prefabs to assign head, left controller, and right controller
   public GameObject vrHeadObjPrefab;
   public GameObject vrLeftCtrlPrefab;
   public GameObject vrRightCtrlPrefab;

   GameObject vrHeadObj;
   GameObject vrLeftCtrl;
   GameObject vrRightCtrl;

   void Start()
   {

       Debug.Log("Start of the vr player");

       if (isLocalPlayer)
       {
           //instantiate prefabs
           CmdInstantiteHeadAndController();
           //disabled conroller meshes at VR player side so it cannont be view by him
           vrLeftCtrl.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
           vrRightCtrl.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
       }
   }

   //Instantiate on start head and vr controller object so that it can be view by normal players
   void CmdInstantiteHeadAndController()
   {
       Debug.Log("instantiateing the controller and head object");
       vrHeadObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(vrHeadObjPrefab);
       vrLeftCtrl = (GameObject)Instantiate(vrLeftCtrlPrefab);
       vrRightCtrl = (GameObject)Instantiate(vrRightCtrlPrefab);

       // spawn the bullet on the clients
       NetworkServer.Spawn(vrHeadObj);
       NetworkServer.Spawn(vrLeftCtrl);
       NetworkServer.Spawn(vrRightCtrl);
   }

   void Update()
   {
       if (!isLocalPlayer)
       {
           return;
       }

       //sync pos on network
       CmdControllerPositionSync();
   }
   //sync position on VR controller objects so that VR player movemnts/action can be viewd by normal user
   [Command]
   public void CmdControllerPositionSync()
   {

       vrHeadObj.transform.localRotation = headObjSource.transform.localRotation;
       vrHeadObj.transform.position = headObjSource.transform.position;
       vrLeftCtrl.transform.localRotation = leftContSource.transform.localRotation;
       vrRightCtrl.transform.localRotation = rightContSource.transform.localRotation;
       vrLeftCtrl.transform.localPosition = leftContSource.transform.position;
       vrRightCtrl.transform.localPosition = rightContSource.transform.position;
   }

   }
   ```

congrats you have done!